# jQuery menu not toggeling class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Menu is not toggling. When I click the toggle button, I see the following error in my JavaScript:

```
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 159,
  "colno": 44
}
```

```js
//java.js
function toggleMenu() {
  document.getElementById('Menu').classlist.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#Menu {
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00ff00;
  left: -400px;
}

#Menu.active {
  display: 0px;
}

#menu ul li {
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  border-top: 4px solid #ff0000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#Menu .toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 410px;
  top: 65px;
}

#Menu .toggle-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

#menu>ul>li {
  border-right: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.bottom {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000;
}

#menu ul ul {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 4px solid #ff0000;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 100%;
  top: -2%;
}

#menu ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#Menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 60%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 56%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>vertical menu with css</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="java.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Menu">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleMenu()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home">Hjem</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-tie">Bjørn</i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">børn 1 </i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">børn 2 </i> </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">børn 3 </i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user">Cille</i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">børn 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">børn 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">børn 3 </a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-tie">David</i></a></li>
          <li class="bottom"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-tie">Fin</i>/a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Ulrik, welcome to SO. It might be a good opportunity to check out our newbie guide. You will earn a badge for that ;) https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: And for future questions: Stay on this page for about half an hour to clearify questions of potential helpers. Just stay here, mostly in several minutes you'll get comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

There where quite a bunch of bugs. Please compare my version with yours and you will find the differences.

1. Take care of case-sensitivity (e.g. `classList` and `classlist`, `#Menu` and `#menu`)
2. Look out for closing HTML tags correctly. There where some mistakes.
3. Remove unncessary elements like `</i>`. It might be a left over from copy-pasting.

Nethertheless, I would recommend you to use a syntax-highlighting tool, so called IDE. Free versions are for instance *VS Code*, *Atom* etc. And afterwards get familiar with the syntax. [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a quite sophisticated and comprehensive source and knowledge base curated by the community.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  document.getElementById('Menu').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#Menu {
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00ff00;
  left: -400px;
  transition: left 360ms ease-in;
}

#Menu.active {
  left: 0;
}

#Menu ul li {
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  border-top: 4px solid #ff0000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#Menu .toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 410px;
  top: 65px;
}

#Menu .toggle-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

#Menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

#Menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

#Menu>ul>li {
  border-right: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.bottom {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000;
}

#Menu ul ul {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 4px solid #ff0000;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 100%;
  top: -2%;
}

#Menu ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#Menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

i {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#Menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 60%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#Menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 56%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>vertical menu with css</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="java.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Menu">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleMenu()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home">Hjem</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-tie">Bjørn</i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">børn 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">børn 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">børn 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user">Cille</i></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">børn 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">børn 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">børn 3 </a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-tie">David</i></a></li>
          <li class="bottom"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-tie">Fin</i></a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that you are not using `classList` correctly, it needs to be camel-cased like below:

```
function toggleMenu() {
  document.getElementById('Menu').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

More of a semantic thing here too, but why is your file called `java.js`? Try to name files based on the functions that they perform, or the features that they encapsulate. It'll save you some headaches later on!